# Error with typescript nodejs when using new keyword in a pc and not using new in another

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase functions with typescript and i'm trying to instantiate google cloud storage with this line:

```
const gCS = gcs({ keyFilename: 'service-account.json' })
```

gcs being `import * as gcs from '@google-cloud/storage'`. It works fine for me but my coworker gets this error when trying to deploy:

> error TS2348: Value of type 'typeof Storage' is not callable. Did you
>   mean to include 'new'?

If he change the line above to:

```
const gCS = new gcs({ keyFilename: 'service-account.json' })
```

The error goes away for him, but then i'm the one having an error:

> error TS2350: Only a void function can be called with the 'new'
>   keyword.

How is that we both need to use different code if we have the same project?

Comment: have you checked that both of you have the same version of the library?

Comment: Also, make sure your `@types` npm package for `@google-cloud/storage` is in sync between the two of you

Answer (score 0):

Check `@type` definitions for both of you, maybe one forgot to save the @types, and check for dependency versions.